# Android Parse Nested JSON Object

Tags: java, android, parsing, json

I have following JSON as a result of a REST Call. I have to parse it as it is, i can't edit.

```
{"result":[
 {"Fields":["CODE","DESCRIPTION"],
  "Row0":["AAAAAAAA","bbbbbbbbb"],
  "Row1":["CCCCCCC","ddddddd"],
  "Row2":["EEEEEEE","ffffffff"],
  "Row3":["GGGGGGG","hhhhhhh"],
  "Row4":["IIIIIII","jjjjjjj"],
  "Row5":["KKKKKKK","llllllll"],
  "Row6":["MMMMMMMM","nnnnnnn"],
  "Row7":["OOOOOOOO","pppppppp"]}
  ]}
```

Once entered in `JSONArray result` how can I parse **only** the Row(n) value dynamically? Having issue.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("REST", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
                Log.d("REST", result.toString());
                /*for (int i = 1; i < result.length(); i++){

                }*/
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes but, to me, is an object, not an array

Comment: did I wrote iterate an array? or  iterate the keys ? ...hello, JSON basics:json is just a map(associative array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy!

**as you get the response and you are getting it in the JSONArray. Then start the loop from the 1st index. This will skip the Fields object.**

And after that you can simply parse your Rows.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("REST", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
                Log.d("REST", result.toString());
                for (int i = 1; i <= result.length(); i++){

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Let me know for any other help..

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm going to post my code solution for nexts asap.